# Платное отключение рекламы в приложении через in-app

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста как в моем коде реализовать платное отключение рекламы от AdMob через in-app.

Код MyClass

```
package test.proj1;

***

public class MyClass extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private InterstitialAd adMob;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ***

        /*Создаем межстраничное объявление adMob*/
        adMob = new InterstitialAd(this);
        adMob.setAdUnitId("ИДЕНТИФИКАТОР");
        // Создаём запрос к AdMob
        AdRequest adRequesti = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        // Начинаем загружать объявление
        adMob.loadAd(adRequesti);
        adMob.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                displayAdMob();
            }
        });
        /*Создаем межстраничное объявление adMob*/

        /*Создаем баннер для AdMob*/
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        /*Создаем баннер для AdMob*/
    }

    /*Проверка загрузки объявления adMob*/
    public void displayAdMob() {
        if (adMob.isLoaded()) {
            adMob.show();
        }
    }
    /*Проверка загрузки объявления adMob*/
}
```

Код layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_activity1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="test.proj1.MyClass"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_activity1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/adMobBanner"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_word_activity"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Я удалил весь лишний код и оставил только куски, где методы для отображения рекламы. Не могу разобраться как именно реализовать отключение

Comment: Вы ожидаете что вам сюда скопипастят документацию? или вы её читали, пробовали и у вас не получилось? Если последнее - расскажите что именно не получилось.

Comment: не ожидаю. Просто думал мне подскажут ресурс (не документацию), где можно про это подробно почитать.

Comment: Что значит "подробно"? Какие подробности, не упомянутые в документации вы ожидаете узнать на стороннем ресурсе?